# Applying multiple CSS classes to an angular select?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I had a normal select in a component's template like this:

```
<select id='target-region' multiple="" class="ui dropdown">
    <option selected value="01">Europe</option>
    <option value="02">North America</option>
    <option value="03">South America</option>
    <option value="04">Asia</option>
    <option value="05">Africa</option>
</select>
```

This dropdown looks something like this:

[image]

I tried to turn it into an angular select like so:

```
<select id="target-region" class="ui dropdown" ng-model="$ctrl.targetRegion" ng-options="item.name for item in $ctrl.TARGET_REGIONS track by item.value" multiple=""></select>
```

And I placed the following in the JS for the component:

```
this.TARGET_REGIONS = [
    { value: '01', name: 'Europe' },
    { value: '02', name: 'North America' },
    { value: '03', name: 'South America' },
    { value: '04', name: 'Asia' },
    { value: '05', name: 'Africa' },
];
this.targetRegion = [this.TARGET_REGIONS[0]];
```

There are no errors, but the dropdown select is now displaying in an odd way:

[image]

My styling seems to not take effect and clicking on the different options does not select them, so it's not even functional.

I inspected the select and saw this:

[image]

This indicates that the `ui dropdown` classes are being applied to an outer wrapper `div` created by angular rather than being applied to the `select`.

At the very least, I'm wondering: how do I make the `ui dropdown` classes apply directly to the select?

Comment: Where is `ui dropdown` coming from initially?

Comment: can you give us a fiddle / css styles to show us what your problem is.

Comment: JS fiddle would be more useful. Please provide more information like, if you are using any plugin for select or any other javascript. Thanks

Comment: I'll try to pare it down so it is in a fiddle.  I did realize that it's using a semantic UI dropdown: https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're directly trying to convert into angular, you need to change some of the javascript/css in order for ng-options to work. if you dont want to change anything, i sugggest you try this

```
<select id='target-region' multiple="" class="ui dropdown">
<option ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.TARGET_REGIONS" value="item.value" >{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is there a way to stop angular styling from being applied to the dropdown?  Because this has the same exact effect as what I already tried.

Comment: is your drop down custom made or have you used a plugin to achieve the styles&behaviour? I you have used a plugin, please let me know which one you've used

Comment: Hi i got this far. http://plnkr.co/edit/pNiKKDHQEZ6KoZhEuDlO?p=preview . im trying to get the first one to get selected. see if it helps you

Comment: the problem is that this uses jquery and angular doesnt go too well with jquery. they're trying to integrate semantic ui with angularjs and its in the testing stages from what i researched.

Comment: Thanks for trying but it doesn't work for me.  :(  I think something else is 
 interfering, but there is so much code involved in this application (which someone else built) that I'm really not sure how to trim it down and put it in a fiddle.

Comment: hmm. did you initialise the drop down? thats when the styles get applied.  take a look at this code i created. http://plnkr.co/edit/pNiKKDHQEZ6KoZhEuDlO?p=preview. it should work no matter how big your application is. it works perfectly well in the link i just shared. try to replicate the same thing in you application.

Comment: I actually realized I should be using Chosen (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) rather than semantic, so I'm going to try to convert the selects to chosen and try working in angular.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i got it to work this way. heres a working fiddle. http://plnkr.co/edit/pNiKKDHQEZ6KoZhEuDlO?p=preview

I suppose you might have forgotten to initialise your dropdown.

```
$(function () {
$('.tag .ui.dropdown').dropdown({allowAdditions: true});  
 });
```